# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Anime & Manga Stack Exchange](http://anime.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://anime.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How does this calendar thing even work?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/15628/how-does-this-calendar-thing-even-work)

**Net Score: 18** (Excellent: 18, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How old were Ed and Al when they performed the human transmutation?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/how-old-were-ed-and-al-when-they-performed-the-human-transmutation)

**Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 14, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Where were we first given the Angels' names?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17267/where-were-we-first-given-the-angels-names)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the relationship between Daedalus and Tomoki?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16855/what-is-the-relationship-between-daedalus-and-tomoki)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Why did Scar only attack the State Alchemists?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17041/why-did-scar-only-attack-the-state-alchemists)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 20, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Is someone who wrote his name in the Death Note allowed to make the eye deal?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16859/is-someone-who-wrote-his-name-in-the-death-note-allowed-to-make-the-eye-deal)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the title of the song that plays during the next episode(18) previews of Parasyte -the maxim-?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/what-is-the-title-of-the-song-that-plays-during-the-next-episode18-previews-of)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/17233/ecchi-manga-about-virgin-girl-and-a-boy-at-a-restaurant

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Need help identifying school anime with short, blonde female character](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16661/need-help-identifying-school-anime-with-short-blonde-female-character)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 10)

---

- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/16919/anime-about-a-girl-fighting-a-demon-and-injuring-a-guy-and-passing-on-her-powers

**Net Score: -11** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 14)

---

Comment: One comment: I marked "Where were we first given the Angels' names?" as "Needs Improvement" not because the question itself is bad (to the contrary, it's really good), but because I had a bear of a time finding it via Google.

Comment: @senshin I actually think that's a good thing--it means we're answering questions that are hard or impossible to find answers to elsewhere.